# How to write this rule?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I need help with a rewrite rule, I couldn't make it work.

The old URL is something like this:

```
/A/B-C.html
```

or

```
/A/B-C.html#postD
```

A: one or more words concatenated with "-".
B: a number
C: one or more words concatenated with "-", it might contain digit.
D: a number

A typical example:

```
/general-discussion/1234-how-are-you.html
```

or

```
/general-discussion/1234-how-are-you.html#post5678
```

The new URL would be like

```
/t1234-how-are-you.html
```

or

```
/t1234-how-are-you.html#post5678
```

I came up with the following format, but it can't match any URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^/[a-z][-a-z]+/([1-9][0-9]*-.+\.html(#post[0-9]+)?)$ /t$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hm. That's strange your regex should work. Not sure what the problem is. Is it possible that something else could be wrong?

Comment: I have other rewrite rules, maybe it's affected by them. I'm very confused right now.

Comment: How can I make it an explicit redirect? 
  
When /general-discussion/1234-how-are-you.html is requested, I want the browser to display /t1234-how-are-you.html, currently the URL /t1234-how-are-you.html works well (it's redirected to a php file internally), but I couldn't make /general-discussion/1234-how-are-you.html work.

Comment: It's like that my redirect was ignored. I want to change the URL before any other redirects that have been working well.

Comment: Never mind, I gave up, changed the URL back.

Comment: >> This is a urgent task and I hope someone can help me out. << I hate when someone says that, because I don't know a question that could wait for years before getting an answer... anyway if it's solved, answer to yourself, vote it for close or flag it and ask an admin.

Comment: Is this rule in an `.htaccess` file? If so, you need to eliminate the initial `/` at the beginning of the pattern - it is stripped from the URL-path by Apache before `.htaccess` sees it.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting here, that the "Fragment" part of the URL (the bit after the #) is browser-local only, and not passed to the web server, so you can't do any matching on that.

The following rule should work for you.

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z][-a-z]+/([0-9]+-[a-z0-9-]+\.html)$ /t$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```